# How to avoid repetitive accessor code?

Tags: javascript, reflection, d3.js, introspection

Below is an example of `d3.js`'s "reusable chart API" (copy-pasted from [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)):

```
function chart() {
  var width = 720, // default width
      height = 80; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`
  }

  my.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return my;
  };

  my.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return my;
  };

  return my;
}
```

Note that the bodies for the `my.width` and `my.height` accessors are almost identical.  I'd like to come up with a way to avoid such repetitive code.

The main obstacle to implementing these accessors programmatically is that they all refer to variables directly in the scope of the enclosing `chart` function, and I don't know how to refer to these variables symbolically/indirectly; without spelling out their names literally, that is.  (Just to be clear, in this case, the variables I'm talking about are the ones declared in the very first two lines of the `chart` function.)

I can think of ways to get around this, such as, for example, defining some "namespace" object, like this:

```
function chart () {
    var _ns = {'width': 720,
               'height': 80};

    ...
}
```

and, whenever necessary, replacing references to `width` and `height` with `_ns['width']` and `_ns['height']`.  The difference, of course, is that now I can *also* write generic code that references `_ns[somevar]` through a *symbolic* reference provided by the `somevar` variable.  E.g. the repetitive accessor definitions above could be replaced with a single iteration over all variable names:

```
['width',
 'height',
 // and whatever else one may want to add later...
].forEach(function (varname) {
    my[varname] = function (value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return _ns[varname];
        _ns[varname] = value;
        return my;
    };
});
```

One downside of this approach is the performance hit caused by the extra level of indirection, even in those situations in which the variables are not being accessed symbolically (e.g. in expressions like `_ns['width']` or `_ns.width`).

Is there some way to leave the variables directly on the `chart` function's scope, but somehow access them symbolically?  IOW, is there something like a *built-in* "namespace" object that can play the part of the `_ns` object above in code that needs to iterate over all the variables symbolically, but without affecting the ability to refer to these variables directory?  (I'm thinking of something analogous to Python's `locals()` built-in function, which returns such a namespace-like object.)

(Of course, there's always `evil`—I mean— `eval`, but I'm trying to keep the code on the up-and-up.)